# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)'

Tags: java, android, listview

I tried to make listview with icon by following [this tutorials](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/). I done everything as the tutorial said but I got this error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference` when I tried to call activity with listview

**Full error I got**

```
03-16 11:07:10.067 3859-3859/th.ac.sd.sdschoolas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: th.ac.sd.sdschoolas, PID: 3859
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{th.ac.sd.sdschoolas/th.ac.sd.sdschoolas.MoreActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
at th.ac.sd.sdschoolas.MoreActivity2.onCreate(MoreActivity2.java:45)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**MoreActivity2.java** (Activity which have a listview)

```
package th.ac.sd.sdschoolas;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.ListActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.Toast;


public class MoreActivity2 extends Activity{

    ListView list;
    String[] itemname ={
            "Safari",
            "Camera",
            "Global",
            "FireFox",
            "UC Browser",
            "Android Folder",
            "VLC Player",
            "Cold War"
    };

    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.ic_cal,
            R.drawable.ic_cal,
            R.drawable.ic_cal,
            R.drawable.ic_cal,
            R.drawable.ic_cal,
            R.drawable.ic_cal,
            R.drawable.ic_cal,
            R.drawable.ic_cal,
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_more2.xml** (Layout file)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="th.ac.sd.sdschoolas.MoreActivity2" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**clist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomListViewAdapter.java**

```
package th.ac.sd.sdschoolas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] itemname;
    private final Integer[] imgid;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.clist, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.itemname=itemname;
        this.imgid=imgid;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.clist, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
        return rowView;

    };
}
```

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` - Your `ListView` is apparently in `activity_more2`, not `activity_main`.

Comment: I didn't notice that It's works Thanks!